# Existence of numerically trivial classes in the algebraic $K$-theory of a threefold with nontrivial Chern characters

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

This is a follow-up question to [my previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405150/why-does-the-chern-character-descend-to-the-numerical-grothendieck-group-for-sur). Let $X$ be a complex smooth projective variety of dimension $d$. Let $K(X)$ denote the Grothendieck group of coherent sheaves on $X$. There is an Euler pairing
$$\chi(E,F) = \sum_{i=0}^{d} (-1)^i \text{dim Ext}^i(E,F)$$
for classes $E, F \in K(X)$. Let $\ker_L$ denote the left radical of $\chi$, that is, $E \in \ker_L$ if and only if $\chi(E,F) = 0$ for all $F \in K(X)$. The subgroup $\ker_L \subset K(X)$ defines an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $K(X)$, called the numerical equivalence. The quotient group $N(X) = K(X)/\ker_L$ is called the numerical Grothendieck group of $X$. We have a ring homomorphism
$$\text{ch}: K(X) \to H^*(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q},$$
which maps $E$ to its Chern character $\text{ch}(E)$ modulo torsion in $H^*(X) := H^*(X,\mathbb{Z})$. Using the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem, it's easy to show that the map $\text{ch}$ descends to $N(X)$ when $X$ is a curve. In the first answer to my previous post, Sasha showed that the result also holds when $X$ is a surface, based on the non-degenerate intersection pairing on the Néron-Severi group $\text{NS}(X)$ of $X$.

Does the result still hold when $X$ is a threefold?

I want to know if there is a counterexample, that is, a class $E \sim 0$ in $K(X)$ for a threefold $X$ such that $\text{ch}(E) \neq 0 $ in $H^*(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Via Riemann-Roch, the image of ${\rm ker}_L$ by the Chern character in the Chow intersection ring of $X$ is the subgroup of cycles numerically equivalent to $0$. It is a part of the standard conjectures that a cycle is numerically equivalent to $0$ iff it is homologically equivalent to $0$ (see Motives, vol I (ed Jannsen et al.) p. 17). So conjecturally, there is no such counterexample in any dimension.

Comment: In particular, if the Hodge conjecture holds for $X$ then there is no counterexample (see same ref., p. 18, Cor. 5-3).

Comment: @DamianRössler Thanks for the enlightening comments! So there are no counterexamples when $X$ is of dimension at most $4$ or when $X$ is an abelian variety by [Lieberman (1968)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373533).